# Trying to understand Etherscan output for token swap via Uniswap

Tags: etherscan, uniswap, transfer

I am trying to understand a token swap transaction via Uniswap on Etherscan. Looking at the Uniswap V2: Router 2 contract for a transaction, I see the following;

[image: Etherscan output]

My question is regarding the second Transfer of 0.002691070168940434 Ether from the Uniswap V2 Router 2 to the From address for the transaction. I see that this amount is added to the swap amount to get the amount in the Value field. What is this amount and what purpose does it serve?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is leftover ETH that was returned to your wallet as a change.

For more detail, you chose to swap by specifying the exact output amount (Doge Reload), so the web calculated the ETH input needed (~0.092 ETH) which was a little more than actual use (~0.089 ETH). So the router returned ~0.002 ETH.

Read more: https://docs.uniswap.org/protocol/V2/reference/smart-contracts/router-02#swapethforexacttokens